# Powershell Installing MSI Quiet Install with Features (ADDLOCAL)

Tags: powershell, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to install an msi. I have written a Powershell script for automating the installation process. But when I try to set which features I want to install the installation fails. See the script I have written to do this below. The script works if I remove the ADDLOCAL section. But I need to set which features to install.

```
 #Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i", `"$MSIDirectoryPathAndFolderName`", "/qn", "/l*v", "`"L:\Log\InstallLog.log`"", "SQLSERVER=`"XXXXXX`"", "DBAUTOBACKUP=`"0`"", "APPPOOLDOMAIN=`"XXXXX`"", "APPPOOLUSER=`"XXX_XXXX`"", "APPPOOLPASSWD=`"XXXX`"", "ADQUERY=`"XXX-XXXX.com`"", "ADDLOCAL=`"AirportMap`"" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

So the problem is with the ADDLOCAL section. I hope somebody could tell me what the problem is. The log file does not tell me what the problem is.

Comment: What is the `ADDLOCAL` parameter supposed to specify?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is earlier in your command with your variable:

```
`"$MSIDirectoryPathAndFolderName`"
```

You're escaping the quotes by using backticks but this doesn't parse correctly as your not enclosing the argument within quotes to signify it's a string.

It either needs to be just the variable name:

```
$MSIDirectoryPathAndFolderName
```

or if you need quotes around the argument (likely if you've folder names with spaces in):

```
"`"$MSIDirectoryPathAndFolderName`""
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ok I found out what the problem was. I was not installing some features that I should have been. It works now.